# Fullscreen window in Xorg causes no keyboard events

Tags: c, linux, x11, xorg

I am coding a simple applicatoin for Xorg (X11, Linux), which should have a fullscreen window.

It seems to be working just fine, the window manager ignores the window so it is positioned properly as fullscreen. But there is a problem, the event loop never gets any KeyPress events. Mouse events are properly received, but no key presses.

```
// assuming some variables are already defined as global here, like display etc.
void main()
{
   unsigned long valuemask = CWOverrideRedirect;
   XSetWindowAttributes attributes;
   Window window;

   window = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, XDefaultRootWindow(display), 0, 0,
              (DisplayWidth(display, screen)), (DisplayHeight(display, screen)), 0, 0, 0);
   attributes.override_redirect = True;
   XChangeWindowAttributes(display, window, valuemask, &attributes);

   for (;;)
   {
       XNextEvent(display, &ev);
       switch (ev.type)
       {
           case KeyPress:
             ... this gets never called if override_redirect = True
       }

       // ... the rest of code
   }
}
```

If I set `attributes.override_redirect = False;` then the window is no longer fullscreen, but keyboard events are received properly.

How do I make it work so the window is fullscreen and can receive proper keyboard events at the same time?

Comment: Tried `XSetInputFocus`?

Comment: AWESOME, this is it ! :=] Feel free to post it as answer. I added this which fixes the thing:    XSetInputFocus(disp,win,RevertToNone,CurrentTime);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`;-)`

Why don't you try `XSetInputFocus(disp, win, RevertToNone, CurrentTime);` ?